# C# MSTest det DataRow value from TestInitialize

Tags: c#, data-driven-tests, .net-4.7.2, mstestv2

I would like to read values of DataRowAttribute from TestInitialize method, so common presetups could be made accrodingly.

```
[TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }


        [ClassInitialize]
        public static void SetupTests(TestContext testContext)
        {
        }

        [DataTestMethod]
        [TestInitialize]
        public void SetupTest()
        {
            var attrValue = TestContext.DataRow;
        }

        [DataTestMethod]
        [DataRow(6,8)]
        public void TestMethod1(int i, int y) 
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(true);
        }
    }
```

TestContext.DataRow returns null since it's expecting DataSourceAtrribute.
Sure I could switch to DataSourceAtrribute but maybe there is a better solution.

Comment: This code seems to need some prerequisites to be able to answer the question.